# What happens when a UDP socket calls a TCP socket

Tags: networking, tcp, udp

The Kurose book mentions that when a TCP socket receives a request it creates another socket and performs 3 way handshake. If the caller is an UDP socket what will happen?

Comment: Nothing. It's impossible. The caller cannot possibly be a UDP socket. Also the 3-way handshake has already happened before the accepted socket is created. If your book really says that it's wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not messing up with the IP level headers, the receiver kernel can figure out what protocol this packet belongs to. There is an explicit mention of data-portion protocol in the [IPV4 header](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc791#section-3.1). So the UDP packet goes to the UDP port if it is open. This also implicitly means the port pools of TCP and UDP are independent.